# Selenium Webdriver Timeout Exception: Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

It's a CRM application where I want to close two pop-ups which are displayed once user login. I have created a method for each pop-up where I am waiting for it's frame to detect and clicking on 'Close' icon to close the pop-up. Below is the code:

```
package base;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TC02_VerificationOfCustomerSearchPage extends 
TC01_LoginToRClaimsCRM{

@Test(priority = 0)
public void PendingEmailPopUPClose() throws InterruptedException, 
AWTException{
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("html/body/div[10]")));

//Close Pending Email pop-up.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button")).click();    
driver.switchTo().frame("InlineDialog1_Iframe");
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void MSCRMPopUPClose() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("html/body/div[10]")));

//Close MSCRM pop-up.
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='buttonClose']/div/img")).click();

driver.switchTo().frame("InlineDialog_Iframe");
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void HomePageVerification() throws InterruptedException, AWTException 
{
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".homeButtonImage")).click();

System.out.println("Home page is displayed.");

Thread.sleep(100);

System.out.println("Verification of Customer Search page UI.");

driver.switchTo().frame("contentIFrame0");

//Verification of Customer Search page UI.

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Main Policy Holder tab.
if(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText().contains("Main Policy Holder")){
    System.out.println("Main Policy Holder tab is displayed.");
    }else{
    System.out.println("Main Policy Holder tab is not displayed.");
    }

//SEARCH CRITERIA label.
if(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText().contains("SEARCH 
CRITERIA")){
    System.out.println("SEARCH CRITERIA label is displayed.");
    }else{
    System.out.println("SEARCH CRITERIA label is not displayed.");
    }

Thread.sleep(1000);

//MPH Name text field.
if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#txtCustomerName")) != null){
    System.out.println("MPH Name text field is displayed.");
    }else{
    System.out.println("MPH Name text field is not displayed.");
    }

Thread.sleep(2000);

//MPH Number text field.
if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#txtCustomerNumber")) != null){
    System.out.println("MPH Number text field is displayed.");
    }else{
    System.out.println("MPH Number text field is not displayed.");
    }

Thread.sleep(1000);

//MPH Policy Number.
if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#txtPolicyNo")) != null){
    System.out.println("MPH Policy Number text field is displayed.");
    }else{
    System.out.println("MPH Policy Number text field is not displayed.");
    }

Thread.sleep(1000);

//SEARCH button.
if(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText().contains("SEARCH")) {
    System.out.println("SEARCH button displayed.");
    }else{
    System.out.println("SEARCH button is not displayed.");
    }

Thread.sleep(1000);

//RESET button.
if(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText().contains("RESET")) {
    System.out.println("RESET button displayed.");
    }else{
    System.out.println("RESET button is not displayed.");
    }

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("Verification Successfull - Customer Search page UI."); 
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver Exception: waiting for frame to be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716039/selenium-webdriver-exception-waiting-for-frame-to-be-available)

Answer (score 0):

Below line is causing you trouble:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("html/body/div[10]")));
```

The method `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt` does what it says. It waits until the frame is available and then, performs `driver.switchTo().frame();` method.

You provided an `xpath` for a frame as `html/body/div[10]` which is 100% incorrect. 
You should provide and xpath to `iframe` tag OR just use `driver.switchTo().frame("InlineDialog1_Iframe");`

If you need to wait until frame is available, make sure `InlineDialog1_Iframe` is an `id` or name`and provide it to`frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt` method like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='InlineDialog1_Iframe or @id='InlineDialog1_Iframe']")));
```

Comment: Now I have used following, but still, it's causing the same error: 
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
  
  //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(("InlineDialog_Iframe")));
  
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='InlineDialog_Iframe']")));
//or 
  
  //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='InlineDialog_Iframe']")));

Comment: @SagarB Please, update your question with code changes, tell us which line of code is throwing an Exception and tell us, what kind of Exception is thrown.

Comment: Below line is throwing an exception-

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: 
waiting for frame to be available: By.xpath: //iframe[@id='InlineDialog_Iframe']

 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='InlineDialog1_Iframe']")));

Comment: @SagarB I need to see "the whole picture". Update your question. I want to see all your code, just like you did when you asked the question.

Comment: @SagarB You should edit existing issue instead of opening a new one.