# Selenium Webdriver Exception: waiting for frame to be available

Tags: java, selenium

It's a CRM application where I want to close two pop-ups which are displayed once user login. I have created a method for each pop-up where I am waiting for its frame to detect and clicking on 'Close' icon to close the pop-up.

Here is the code:

```
package base;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TC02_VerificationOfCustomerSearchPage extends TC01_LoginToRClaimsCRM{

@Test(priority = 0)
public void PendingEmailPopUPClose() throws InterruptedException, AWTException{
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='InlineDialog1_Iframe']")));

//Close Pending Email pop-up.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.switchTo().frame("InlineDialog1_Iframe");
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void MSCRMPopUPClose() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='InlineDialog_Iframe']")));

//Close MSCRM pop-up.
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='buttonClose']/div/img")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

}
```

Comment: Try to change `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='InlineDialog1_Iframe']")));` to `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("InlineDialog1_Iframe")));`

Comment: Which iframe is it not detecting? Plus you need to add 'driver.switchTo().defaultContent();' at the end of first test. Else the second iframe will be looked inside the first iframe.

Comment: @ Grasshopper - It's not detecting the first `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='InlineDialog1_Iframe']")));`

Comment: @RafałLaskowski Changed it to `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("InlineDialog1_Ifr‌​ame"));` ,still getting the same exception.

Comment: @SagarB Which line is causing you troubles?

Comment: `FAILED: PendingEmailPopUPClose
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available: InlineDialog1_Ifr??ame (tried for 30 second(s) with 30000MILLISECONDS interval)`

Comment: Are you sure that `iframe` is available at the beginning of the test?

Comment: @RafałLaskowski - Yes `iFrame`is at the beginning of the test.